# Win10 - Non-Shared drives appear in remote list

Tags: windows-10

Win10 Pro for those who need to know.

dang. this is kinda tough to explain. i have 3 drives. one, i shared, the other two, i did not. when i go to access them from, say, my Android, i see ALL the drives, listed as $A, $B and $D, and ANOTHER named entry for the shared drive (eg. $D -> Spats). stranger still, i can only access the named drive (as expected) but NOT the other $ designated drives.

1)  why am i seeing the othet drives AT ALL?
2)  how do i fix it so i ONLY see Spats?

TIA crew!

WR!

Comment: A dollar sign in front of the sharename is the way to hide a share. What Android app are you using?

Comment: Solid Explorer. and, ya, i thought that was the case... so i am surprised to see them listed... O_o

Comment: Me to, that's why I asked for the app.

Answer (score 0):

time for the Bloody Moron Cap to come out... head-smackingly simple:  i had Show Hidden turned on. O_o  good grief...

apologies for wasting your time folks.  i go to sit in the corner and think about what i have done...  :'(